# How to use TMS570 microcontroller UART to communicate to another device?

Tags: uart, communication, digital-communications, tms570

I am trying to use a TMS570 to communicate to another device through UART.

The pin diagram is here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/spnu611/spnu611.pdf

I tried following the following tutorial for how to use the SCI/UART on the microcontroller, but I realized that it only contains instructions for how to communicate between the PC and the microcontroller, not for how to communicate to another device using UART.

I posed this question [on the TI E2E forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20181119222020/https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/hercules/f/312/p/565137/2071932), and got the following advice:

> The TMS570LS1224 has two UARTs, one is a LIN/SCI2 combination and the other is just a plain SCI. In the Launchpad schematic on sheet 12, section A1, you can see that the LIN pins are connected to U7. U7 is the chip that creates the XDS110. The XDS110 is not only a JTAG controller, but also acts as a USB to Serial port for your PC. In the example code from the tutorial SCI2 was writing to the PC and receiving from the PC. The LIN pins are already used on the Launchpad.
>
> If you want to connect two launchpads together by a UART, I suggest you use the plain SCI, pins J2-3 and J2-4.

However, I am not sure how to configure HalCoGen to set up the pins in this way, and what methods to use in Code Composer Studio to communicate through them. Would anyone have any advice?

LaunchPad Schematic: https://www.ti.com/lit/df/sprr399/sprr399.pdf
TMS570 data sheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spns190b/spns190b.pdf

Answer (score 2):

> However, I am not sure how to configure HalCoGen to set up the pins in this way, and what methods to use in Code Composer Studio to communicate through them. Would anyone have any advice?

typically:

1) start reading the user manuals of HalCoGen and CCS, get yourself familiar with the tools / environments;

2) look at sample code, vs. the datasheet;

3) start coding and debug it on your hardware.

the same approach you take on pretty much any (mcu) devices.

Answer (score 1):

as stated by the answer connect this pins like this J2-3 (RX of board1) - J2-4 (TX of board2) and connect J2-4 (TX of board1) to J2-3 (RX of board2)

the launchpad use RM46L850 micro controller, see page 153, which clearly specify all the features of serial communication [RM46L850](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spns184c/spns184c.pdf)